# JMOCKIT: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute

Tags: jmockit

Hi I am getting the below error when starting my server with jmockit-1.9.jar in classpath. Any idea how to resolve this?

`14:35:58,932 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:12000-4) java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute
14:35:58,933 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:12000-4)  at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.loadAgentAndDetachFromThisVM(AgentLoader.java:115`

Comment: Looks like it is a problem of Jmockit unable to load the classes in openjdk.. refer this ticket https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/114

Comment: that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html#runningTests) says:

> Make sure the specified version (here specified in the
>   "jmockit.version" property) is the one you actually want. Find the
>   current version in the development history page. JMockit also requires
>   the -javaagent JVM initialization parameter to be used; when using the
>   Maven Surefire plugin for test execution, it's specified as follows:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version> <!-- or some other version -->
      <configuration>
         <argLine>
            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/jmockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar
         </argLine>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```